# Should sorting be done in java or oracle for performance reasons

Tags: java, performance, oracle, sorting

If I make a oracle query from my java application and that oracle query returns a large list, what is more efficient sorting: using the oracle order by clause or doing the sort in java using Collections.sort(list)?
I intuitively understand that doing it in oracle is faster but cannot find a reason

Comment: Indices in SQL databases are ordered on entry. This means you incur the ordering/indexing cost on insertion. After that, if the column is indexed, the index is _already ordered_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this answer about the question: [database sort vs. programmatic java sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883264/database-sort-vs-programmatic-java-sort)

Basicially, if you have a few rows of data (10-100) sorting it from code would be faster, otherwise use the database, they're design for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

If the column is indexed , then I believe `ORDER BY` in DB would be processed faster than sorting the resultset in Java. Databases are designed to deal with large data volumes and it has various optimization techniques. Again depending on the actual query string , the database optimizer may choose a query plan that returns the data in order without performing a sort. Well if the volume is large , I would leave the work to DB than loading the entire result in memory and sorting it in Java, leave alone CPU usage etc...

Comment: Even without the index Oracle, as any other serious DBMS, will likely sort much faster than Java. As you said, databases are designed to efficiently process large volumes of data. Sort algorithms in databases get very much attention so they tend to be extremely efficient. Database servers usually have much more memory than clients. If multiple connections request the same result set, the sorted results will likely be shared, while on the client side each session will have to sort its own result. These are some of the reasons you shouldn't sort on the client side.