# Keeping a large sorted User cache with an intensive comparator

Tags: java, mysql, algorithm, sorting, data-science

I have a large data set (100,000+ users) that needs to be cached and sorted for use at all times during a game's runtime. The system is of users in a game that have the ability to earn points. The system is broken up into parts for completing game tasks as follows:

**Category Score:** Positive integer score earned from  completing tasks in a category of the game.
**Category Rank**: Rank (0 -> n) of users sorted by top score in a category.
**Category Worth**: The worth for the category rank in a given category. I.E: "Fighting" rank 0 gives you 10 global points while "Fighting" rank 1 give you 9 global points.
**Global Score**: A summation of points earned by each user depending on the category rank and score. I.E: If you earn a 0th place in fighting (worth 10 points), but 2nd place in defense (worth 8 points), your global score is 18th points.

**Global Rank**: Rank (0 -> n) sorted by global score.

In the MySQL table keeping this data, each entry is a kept in a row of `(player [UUID], category [String], score [Integer])`. However, since data is modified every second based on user gameplay and the user needs to be able to access the global and individual category leaderboards at any time, this information needs to be cached in memory and pre-sorted to remain efficient. As an additional caveat, both category order and global order need to be kept available as separate data points considering a player may want to view an individual category rank and score as well as their global rank and score.

Currently, the system achieves this with the following steps:

1. Get all entries from MySQL and log them into individual `User` objects with just the raw score for each category
2. Put all users into a category cache `(HashMap<Category, ArrayList<User>>)` with the list being sorted by their category score (this will be used for individual category leaderboards)
3. Loop through each category in the aforementioned category cache and put that user into a global cache `(ArrayList<User>)` with points summed. This is then sorted by total points which gives them their rank based on their index in the list.

The current means of sorting are by using Java 8's built in `List#sort()` with comparators using the category's score and the global score respectively.

Currently, the sorting of this data with 100,000+ players and 25 categories is around 40-60 seconds with a massive amount of memory and CPU power being used to sort each pass through. This refreshes every 10 minutes and is severely impacting server performance.

Any idea on how to re-work this system to alleviate some of the pressure on the server?

Edit: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883264/database-sort-vs-programmatic-java-sort) shows that for larger data sets, database sorting is more efficient, but I it doesn't fully cover how the ranking would be approached considering ranks are not based by one column, but rather a 25 calculations done based on the rank.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [database sort vs. programmatic java sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883264/database-sort-vs-programmatic-java-sort). SQL is efficient at sorting, make it do the heavy lifting for you and see if it makes a difference. If you want to stick with Java, then please show the relevant sorting code, it may be that your current implementation is done in an inefficient manner.

Comment: @sorifiend I am not particularly against database sorting if it is a more efficient option. Which if I am to understand correctly, your link seems to showcase quite well.

I am, however, a bit confused on the implementation of keeping this sorted efficiently. If you were to say, query the table for the top 10 users when a user requests it, would this not have to perform an intensive calculation of sorting the table each time? Considering the table isn't tracking users, but rather their individual category scores.

Comment: You only do your update/sort once every 10 min? So there would be no live query, rather you would retrieve the already sorted data instead? How are you storing the sorted data, is it in a Java list? Or in a new SQL table?

Comment: @sorifiend I should clarify, the previous system had live data being inserted into the database. This was all kept unsorted. The refresh every 10 minutes is so players have updated data.

In the new situation, if I understand correctly, would be with only MySQL sorting being done. This would keep in mind that new data will be inserted into that database frequently and existing data will update as new scores come in. Thus, I imagine that data would need to be re-sorted when queried

Comment: @Nate Please see my answer.  I show how MySQL can produce top 10 without sorting live.  The database answer isn't quite perfect.  As I outline, it is possible to do better, but it does take some work.

Comment: I would start by peppering the code with 'print' statements that show how long each component took.  You may find that only one or two tasks is taking most of that 40-60s.  Then rethink its design, its 'need', and how frequently it is needed.

Comment: Is a "player" in exactly one "category"?  (This may lead to using the clustering of a PRIMARY KEY or the "covering" of a secondary INDEX.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a database index kept in an [ordered data structure](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/recitations/rec25-B-trees/rec25.html) with a command like this:

```
create index category_order using btree
on your_table (category, score DESC, player);
```

And now run the following query:

```
select score, player
from your_table
where category = 'your category'
order by score DESC;
```

MySQL should be able to answer this query by scanning the index and returning data in order.  Since the necessary data is already kept in order, this should be very fast compared to the current approach.

Unfortunately MySQL can't tell you ranks as well as ordering. So you have to actually run the full query periodically to store ranks.  This doesn't matter for showing a live top 10 result.  But it won't show person 10,000 their rank improvement right after they do something.

For that you can cheat.  You can store a score -> rank mapping in a table.  When someone changes their score, you use their new score to estimate their new rank, then show them a page of data around that rank.  As long as you update the mapping regularly, most users won't notice the cheat.  But it is a cheat.

Can we not cheat?  Of course!  But it will take effort.

There is no reason in principle why a sorted data structure (eg red-black tree, btree) can't also calculate ranks on the fly.  But in practice it requires keeping track of how many elements are below the node at each node.  Since that is not often asked for, standard implementations don't include that.

But you can write your own.  For example [here is a Red-Black tree](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/33balanced/RedBlackBST.java.html) that supports rank.  (Careful of copyright, either write your own or ask for permission to use that.) So if you keep a category in such a data structure, and also keep track of users and their values, you should be able to take a user, look at their score, look them up in the tree, find their rank, and (with a little cleverness) ALSO return a page of data of people around any rank you want.  This data structure should be able to handle tens of thousands of requests and/or modifications per second on a single CPU.  Replicate multiple copies of it in a well-designed service and people can always get live results, with only millisecond delays.  And without any compromises.

If you need help beyond simply knowing that it is possible, well, you can contact me at my user name @gmail.com to discuss a consulting rate...

Comment: I can see how this is quite useful for grabbing both rank and score for categories, but how would that query efficiently work into a global ranking? 

Considering that also has to do the additional calculus of summing all your categories you gained some point value from and then getting your rank in that list? Or are you saying to sort categories from the query and then do that additional sorting in Java?

Comment: Add a new category in MySQL which is named "total" and is maintained as the sum of the other categories.  Then query that for global.

Comment: @Nate Another option I ran across. https://redis.io/commands/zrange/ with a little embedded Lua script allows you to keep live data, queryable on the fly, with queries scalable across multiple machines with replication. It is the millisecond response time but already mostly built for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Plan A**

Top 10 out of 100,000 -- There is a thing called a "priority queue".  In some situations, it is quite efficient.  Use it to hold the 100K users and their scores.  It can deliver the "top 1" (highest ranking user) in O(log N) time; compare this to a full sort is O(N*log N).  (N=100,000).

But you pay for it in inserts and deletes and updates -- each single item change is also O(log N).  And in order to always have the top 1 (or 10) available, you must update the PQ whenever anyone's score changes.

MySQL does not have a way to do this.  I would hop that there is a Java package to do it, otherwise you would have to implement it.

To implement it in Java means that you need to be able to get to the same Java instance.  The alternative involves going to MySQL (or some other 'persistent' store); this is costly.

Please provide the big picture of the architecture -- 1 server or many?  One process or many?  HTTP or REST or what?

**Plan B**

This assumes multiple processes/threads and/or servers are involved, but a single persistent store (eg, a MySQL table) is holding the "score" for each user.

The various processes are updating the score whenever something changes.

The query is something like `SELECT user_id, ... FROM tbl ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10`.  If you need to fetch info from other table(s), then do:

```
SELECT scores.userid, scores.score
       ... -- stuff from other tables
    FROM ( SELECT user_id, score FROM tbl
             ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10 ) AS scores
    JOIN ... AS x  ON scores.user_id = x.user_id
    etc
    ORDER BY scores.score DESC    -- yes, again
```

That makes sure to find the 10 rows without having to touch all 100,000.

Have this composite index: `INDEX(score, user_id)`

As you display the top-10, your app code can add 1,2,...,10.  (Do not ask SQL to do it.)

Comment: You are solving the problem of showing a top leaderboard.  But not the harder problem of being able to tell each player their own rank.

Comment: @btilly - I give the actual rank for anyone in the top X percentage; but give only percentile for lower-ranked players.  Yes, it is a compromise.  But dynamically counting or sorting 100M rows is likely to take too long.

Comment: I disbelieve. With the right data structure returning a sorted block of `k` people from `n` takes `O(k + log(n))`. Finding a person's rank takes `O(log(n))`. I pointed out elsewhere that Redis HAS the right data structure. Redis has significant data limits. But we were asked for only 100k. With Redis and read-only replicas I could handle 10 million people, 10k updates/second and unlimited reads.

Comment: Sure, Redis can one item out of 10M.  But can it _count_ 100K items to find the ordinal of that item?

Comment: Yes. See https://redis.io/commands/zrank/. See https://redis.io/docs/manual/data-types/#sorted-sets for more.  Note that, "Build a leaderboard in a massive online game..." is explicitly listed as an intended use case.

Comment: @btilly - Cool!  How do you change an individual's score?  Maybe ZADD myset 17 'three'?  Is "17" the "score"?  Or the "rank+1"?

Comment: @btilly - I guess Redis has one in-RAM binary tree for key->value and a second binary tree for value->key.  And there is a counter in each tree node that dead-reckons the number of descendants of the node.  Changing a score requires a lookup in the first tree and two actions in the other tree (delete+add), plus associated increment/decrement of the counters.  All of that could be done in about 51 "operations" for 100K users and their scores.  Then another 17 ops to get the "rank".  Not bad, _assuming it is all in RAM_.  (And not practical in SQL.)

Comment: 17 is the score, three is the key.  Ties are broken lexicographically by key. As with all Redis, it is done single threaded in RAM.  (Makes locking simple!) Hence the data limits. But within those limits it is very fast. And with replication you get unlimited read parallelism.

Comment: With a lot of work, the same thing could also be done in a parallelized way in a distributed store, but locking and concurrency would have to be done very, very carefully.  But the idea is similar.